# Can anyone tell what kind of berry/currant this is?

Tags: botany, species-identification

[image: Some kind of currant]

I found this currant-like plant in Helsinki, Finland. It seems very similar to red currant but it has hairs on its fruits, and the fruits are pear-shaped. Can anyone please identify this plant? Many thanks!

Comment: Did you find it growing wild or did it seem cultivated?

Comment: @picapica It seemed to be growing wild, next to a street!

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this is a species of *Ribes* (Grossulariaceae, vernacular Finnish: herukat), and that it is not native to Finland.

I would guess that it might be a variety of *R. rubrum* L., but it also might be a [species unrecorded in Finland so far](http://koivu.luomus.fi/kasviatlas/taxa.php?key=Ribes&year=2015). You might consider sending the photo to someone at Helsinki Botanical Garden, or at the Natural History Museum. (If you got a twitter account, you might just sent the link to this page to @Raino_Lampinen and ask on his opinion.)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! I should try out the Twitter :) I'll update it here when I get the answer!